# React MUI partially collapsible grid sections

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I wanna make a scalable grid of items were items with `showDefault: true` always are shown at the top and then one can click arrow button to expand grid to also show the items with `showDefault: false`

Any way to make this?

```
interface IGridItem {
  id: string
  name: string
  showDefault: boolean
}

function MyGrid(){
  return (
    <>
      <IconButton onClick={}><ArrowIcon/></IconButton>
      <Box
        sx={{
          display: "grid",
          gridTemplateColumns: "repeat(auto-fill, minmax(187, 1fr))"
        }}
      >
        {items.filter(item => item.showDefault).map(item => <MyGridItem key={item.id} item={item}/>)}
        {items.filter(item => !item.showDefault).map(item => <MyGridItem key={item.id} item={item}/>)}
      </Box>
    </>
  )
}

function MyGridItem({item}: {item: IGridItem}){
  return (
    <Box>
      {item.name}
    </Box>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could conditionally render the items that you want, whether the non-default ones should be shown:

```js
interface IGridItem {
  id: string
  name: string
  showDefault: boolean
}

function MyGrid(){
  const [showDefault, setShowDefault] = useState(false);

  const handleOnShowDefault = () => {
     setShowDefault(prev => !prev);
  }

  return (
    <>
      <IconButton onClick={handleOnShowDefault}><ArrowIcon/></IconButton>
      <Box
        sx={{
          display: "grid",
          gridTemplateColumns: "repeat(auto-fill, minmax(187, 1fr))"
        }}
      >
        {items.filter(item => item.showDefault).map(item =>
          <MyGridItem key={item.id} item={item}/>
        )}

        {showDefault && items.filter(item => !item.showDefault).map(item => 
             <MyGridItem key={item.id} item={item}/>
        )}
      </Box>
    </>
  )
}

function MyGridItem({item}: {item: IGridItem}){
  return (
    <Box>
      {item.name}
    </Box>
  )
}
```

Comment: this works pretty well.. but i cant seem to get it to transition when it opens and collapses

Comment: You could use the [`Transition`](https://mui.com/components/transitions/#collapse) component from `mui`, though it requires a more complex example, in which you should calculate the `height` and so on of the screen.